# Why flutter web video doesn't work after I publish. But it works in localhost

Tags: flutter

When **I debug mode it works** perfectly. But after I publish it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your main manifest in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest